# Why do many pass an event in the callback

Tags: javascript

I recently learned that you don't have to pass the event as a parameter for an event. But I wonder why many still pass the event.

**Example click event**

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", myfn.bind());

function myfn(event) {
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(this);
}
```

Is there a reason for this? Because that works to:

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", myfn.bind());

// without passing event
function myfn() {
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: Read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @JuniusL. Thank you for the link. Can you give an answer to the question in 2 to 3 sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
btn.addEventListener("click", myfn.bind());

// without passing event
function myfn() {
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(this);
}
```

Above works because `event` can access through a global variable, `window.event`

> The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is
> currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an
> event handler, the value is always undefined.

```
function myfn(anotherArgName) {
  console.log(anotherArgName === window.event); // true
}
```

Not recommend to use the 2nd one as MDN docs [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event),

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some
> browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> may cease to work at any time.

Plus depending on external dependencies makes your function hard to read, test & maintain.

Comment: To summarise again. It is better to pass event than parameter, right?

Comment: Its better to use `event` ( or whatever name you give. `e`, `evt` or anything ) parameter and use that but not the global variable `event` i.e `window.event`